# How to make the game wait for an animation to finish?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm teaching myself andengine while trying to make a match-3 puzzle, so far I have a grid of gems that I populate and can move then around. Matching gems and new gems falling is working already. My problem is that the game keeps flowing while animations runs. How can I make the flow suspend until movement is done?

I use entity modifiers for the gems animations. `MoveYModifier` for the fall and `PathModifier` for the swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the entity modifier and execute some code at the beginning of the modification and on its end

```
MoveYModifier yourModifier = new MoveYModifier(3, 0, 10)
{
        @Override
        protected void onModifierStarted(IEntity pItem)
        {
                super.onModifierStarted(pItem);
                // Your action after starting modifier
        }

        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem)
        {
                super.onModifierFinished(pItem);
                // Your action after finishing modifier
        }
};

yourEntity.registerEntityModifier(yourModifier);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, you are kinda late =P. I even forgot about this question. Nonetheless, your anwser is correct, thanks for posting.